# Why circuit breaker trips randomly?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Have a finished bedroom in basement which has its own circuit breaker (15 amp).

There are 3 recessed light and 6 outlets in the room.

Each recessed light has max 9 watt capacity.

I double checked outlet and recessed light are fine and well connected.

This is how the circuit trips-

1. once circuit breaker tripped after connecting a floor lamp to one of the outlet. I did use outlet tester and didn’t see any problem ( when the light was light switch was off and breaker ON).
2. when turn on ceiling light using single pole switch, I did tripped. How tripping again and again when I turn on switch. Didn’t find wrong there though.

I also I found it doesn’t trip always when turning on light.

What could be the problem and how to diagnose the issue ?

[image]

Comment: What else is plugged into all the outlets?  Is there anything else on the circuit outside of the bedroom?

Comment: Type of circuit breaker?  If just a simple breaker, you have a short that happens during movement of the wires, maybe a ground just too close to a hot but not touching.

Comment: Added picture.  There is nothing plugged in any of the outlet. There is nothing outside of the bed room. This s AFCI breaker.

Comment: And the breaker is just 1 year old

Comment: One more thing, I turned light on first time on them OFf. Did the same on 2nd time. Third time it tripped.

Comment: Google "Time Saver Diagnostics", specifically the part where it talks about holding the button and timing 2, 5 or 10 seconds to trip.    Then [edit] your question to add the results.

Answer (score 4):

So, the FIRST thought should be - the breaker **is working properly**, and there's an actual arc fault to **find and fix** (typically a loose connection.)

The second thought (which you might look at first, just to eliminate it) is that this one might be wired incorrectly - or that the neutral may be connected (shorted) to another circuit's neutral or to ground if this is one that has "limited GFCI protection" as part of the AFCI function. That appears to apply to this version, as the instructions linked below state "This product does not meet the requirements for Class A ground-fault circuit protection." That wording implies to me that it provides some, and I know that's common for AFCI breakers.

There's a procedure to find out why it tripped in the installation instructions:

[image: fault indication section]

*Image source https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_Doc_Ref=48840-249-01&p_enDocType=Instruction+sheet&p_File_Name=48840-249-01.pdf*

That will tell you more about what you're looking for, fault-wise.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check my circuit breaker now , it’s seems it tripping randomly after certain times I turn on/off switch.  
Today It tripped when I on/off 10 times with 1 sec gap between. I

Comment: So, that suggests that the light circuit wiring has a loose connection, and some of the time it's loose enough to arc fault, while other times it's not. But knowing what type of fault you're actually getting would be helpful to guide the direction to look.